# when Base Currency of store is changed product price not converting to base currency only the currency symbol is changing

Tags: magento-1.9

when i change the base currency from INR to USD The Price is not converting to USD only the Currency  Symbol is changing for example product with price RS 2000 is changed to USD 2000 the price conversion is not happening.